# How to connect mainframe data to ClearCase?

Tags: clearcase, mainframe

I joined a new company using Mainframes (z/os) for developement, documentation, design and testing. Now we are planning to migrate the whole system to ClearCase for version control.

My question is: are there any connectors I can use to connect the mainframe to ClearCase, so that the user can checkin/checkout straight in to their mainframe environment?

I am looking for a couple of solutions to do this, like tools I can use and so on.

Comment: I think you will need to supply further information on exactly what these mainframes are - ie. Hardware, OS, and software.

Comment: z/OS is the OS (from the question) and it generally only runs on _one_ type of hardware, that from IBM (discounting toys like Hercules of course).

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about storing the stuff in Clearcase on a distributed platform and having it accessible from z/OS, I'm not aware of any way to do that but, since z/OS comes with a full blown UNIX environment built in with access to both the UNIX file systems and z/OS data sets, it may well be doable.

---

What *is* doable, since we've done it (and, in fact, we developed large chunks of it) is to access data on the mainframe from a distributed platform.

RD/z (Rational Developer for System z, although it may have changed names by now) has a plug-in which allows Eclipse to tie in to the mainframe quite easily. It uses a started task to communicate with SCLM as its primary library manager but, from memory, you can directly access the non-SCLM data sets as well.

If you combined that with a Clearcase Eclipse plug-in, you could quite easily put together a system which, while it kept everything in a Clearcase repository, could quite easily push it up the the mainframe and build it automatically, pulling down the built artefacts if you also wanted them stored in Clearcase.

All from one environment. Of course, the dinosaurs will question your sanity at storing their 'precious' in a flaky distributed system - that fact that both products come out of IBM in no way alleviates the rivalry between mainframers and lesser mortals :-)

> If that's not ideal and the company has a mainframe (and it appears they do), they will also have a support contract with IBM. Best bet would be to raise a Q&A with IBM to see if there are any solutions already out there - please don't raise a PMR for this, it's not a bug and that just annoys support/development and makes the monthly targets harder to meet :-) Alternatively, ask [the people that would know](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/forums/forum.jspa?forumID=1131). IBM developers monitor these forums and should be able to help you out more than I.

On the off-chance that you don't have a developerWorks account, keep an eye on [this question](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=352339&tstart=0) that I started on your behalf. I'm actually interested in the results myself, since part of my day job is the marrying of the mainframe and distributed worlds. Although, unfortunately, it sometimes seems like it's about as successful as most Hollywood or other celebrity marriages :-)

Comment: clearcase will be on windows and they just using mainframe to compile the code. does it make a difference

Comment: Not really, you can script RD/z in headless mode for automated builds. So you could pull stuff out of Clearcase, upload it to z/OS, run the build process on the mainframe and download the artefacts again. This is something you might want to ask on the forums (see the update).

Comment: Some advice (and a shameless plug for a friend of mine), get yourself a copy of http://www.amazon.com/What-Earth-Mainframe-David-Stephens/dp/1409225356 and have a look at some other questions tagged `mainframe`, specifically my answers to them - I think you'll be surprised. Today's mainframes aren't your grandfather's mainframes :-)

Comment: Hi Paxdiablo; after doing some research i am thinking of using TSO client from clearcase. any suggestion on this.

Comment: Yes, don't :-) TSO is okay for what it is but there's a reason why everyone uses ISPF. TSO is not the friendliest interface in the world and you have to _really_ know what you're doing. Of course, if you're talking about a Clearcase plugin for TSO access, that may hide a lot of the detail from you. I haven't used this combo so can't really comment intelligently on it.